# CANNOT IMPORT MOCKV3AGGREGATOR FROM BROWNIE

Tags: python, solidity, smartcontracts, brownie, aggregator

Ran the code as shown but I the contract is not being deployed, I keep getting this error ImportError: cannot import name 'MockV3Aggregator' from 'brownie'. Any help would be appreciated, thank you, the brownie-config file is also below.

helpful_scripts.py

```
from brownie import network, config, accounts, MockV3Aggregator

FORKED_LOCAL_ENVIRONMENTS = ["mainnet-fork", "mainnet-fork-dev"]
LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS = ["development", "ganache-local"]


def get_account(index=None, Id=None):
    if index:
        return accounts[index]
    if id:
        return accounts.load(Id)
    if (
        network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS
        or network.show_active in FORKED_LOCAL_ENVIRONMENTS
    ):
        return accounts[0]

    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
```

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
networks:
  default: development
  mainnet-fork:
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419' 
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Comment: Mockv3aggregator is not the property of brownie..  you need to import it from your mockv3aggregator contract or in chainlink contract npm

Comment: Already solved it actually, thanks. Just like you said, it wasn't available in my contract folder.